# string convert to json in android

Tags: java, android, json

```
    client.post("http://10.0.2.2/project/process/selectalluser.php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            Integer contacts = controller.getContactsCount();
            Log.d("Reading contacts: ", contacts+"");
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            Log.d("Reading response: ", response.length()+"");
            System.out.println(response);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MySQL DB has been informed about Sync activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
            System.out.println("onFailure");
            System.out.println(statusCode);
            System.out.println(error);
            System.out.println(content);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Then my php :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin_tbl`");
                            if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $basicinfo = array();
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $basicinfo[] = array(
                        'email' => $selected_row['email'],
                        'username' => $selected_row['username'],
                        'password' => $selected_row['password'],
                        'fname' => $selected_row['fname'],
                        'mname' => $selected_row['mname'],
                        'lname' => $selected_row['lname'],
                        'suffix' => $selected_row['suffix'],
                        'status' => $selected_row['status']);
                }
                echo json_encode($basicinfo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                //return $basicinfo;
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'error' => false,
                    'message' => "No record found!"
                ));
                exit;
            }
        }
```

This is my code i want to convert the response which is of type string to JSON so i can count how many records are there. But I get error of `Unhandled Exception: org.json.JSONException` in line `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);`

The line `System.out.println(response);` will result below:

> I/System.out: [{"email":"admin@gmail.com","username":"admin","password":"admin","fname":"Bradley","mname":"Buenafe","lname":"Dalina","suffix":"","status":"1"}]

How to correctly convert this format of String to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your response isn't a `JSONObject` but a `JSONArray`, the `[]` indicate an array. A normal object wouldn't have those. You can use

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

Comment: do i need to have a specific import for that i wasnt able to mention this but i tried this already

Comment: `org.json.JSONArray`?

Comment: Update the code in your question with the JSONArray and the specific exception you are getting.

Comment: updated the question with the php page where the value is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
```

Use:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
```

As you have shown in the System.out, you are getting response as json array and not the json object.

Json array always starts with '[' and json object always starts with '{'

Comment: do i need to have a specific import for that i wasnt able to mention this but i tried this already

Comment: Similar import as of JSONObject i.e. `org.json.JSONArray`. If you are still facing the issue, please post latest logs, because as per old logs this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
     Log.d("Reading response: ", jsonArray.length()+"");
} catch (JSONException e) {
     // Do something with the exception
}
```

I read somewhere you need to put in try catch. I did and it is not having error and also returned the correct length.

I am not sure if this is hackish way of solving this problem.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense

Comment: what do you mean right now i am using the try catch solution is there any reason this will fail? @NielsMasdorp

Comment: Well, the try catch only catches the `Exception` preventing your app from crashing but it won't prevent the actual `Exception` from being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about JSON but when I had to use it I looked into a github mode from google called. Gson - https://github.com/google/gson You just need to get the library and add the Maven dependency.

Once you do that you can use toJson() and fromJson() to convert from Java objects to JSON and back.

Hope it helps :)